# Trigonometry $\sin \alpha+ \sin \beta=1$ and ...

Tags: trigonometry

$\text{Let $\sin \alpha+\sin \beta=1$ and $\cos \alpha+\cos \beta=-\sqrt{3}$}.$

$\text{Find the exact value of $\cos(\alpha-\beta).$}$

Comment: Try squaring both sides of each equation and use the fact that $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$

Answer (score 5):

$(\sin \alpha+\sin \beta)^2=\sin^2 \beta+\sin^2 \beta+2\sin \alpha\sin \beta=1$

$(\cos \alpha)+\cos \beta)^2=\cos^2 \alpha+\cos^2 \beta+2\cos \alpha\cos\beta=3$

adding the both $2(\cos \alpha\cos\beta+\sin \alpha\sin \beta)+2=2\cos(\alpha-\beta)+2=4$, $\cos(\alpha-\beta)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

note that $$\sin(x)+\sin(y)=2\cos\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)$$ and $$\cos(x)+\cos(y)=2\cos\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

The given trig expressions are symmetric in $(\alpha , \beta) $ and  do not change when arguments  $\alpha , \beta $ are interchanged. Consequently  some expressions  like

$$\sin (\alpha - \beta)$$

and

$$\cos (\alpha - \beta) $$

with a zero argument become $(0,1).$